# MARS Mips open file default folder

Tags: mars-simulator

Is there a way to set the default folder when clicking File>Open?

MARS always shows the user folder for me (home/diogo/).

It only shows another folder when I have already a file opened (shows that file directory).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux open the terminal, navigate to the desired folder and launch mars with java -jar PathToMarsJar